# DocuSign REST API returns HTML?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I tried making a request to DocuSign to get the list of Documents so that I can traverse through the list for URIs.

I made request to:

[https://account-d.docusign.com/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents](http://%20json:%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headers:%20%7B%20Authorization:%20'Bearer%20'+docusign_credentials.token%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20followAllRedirects:%20true)

Headers: 
{ 
        json: true,
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+token },
        followAllRedirects: true
}

This request returns HTML page which is not much readable. Status is 200 OK

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If DocuSign is returning HTML, it's generally giving you a 404 page because you've hit an invalid URL in an environment that isn't expecting an API call.

The account server (`account-d.docusign.com` in Demo and `account.docusign.com` in Prod) is intended to only be used for authentication, and pulling information about the currently authenticated user. It can't be used to create or manage envelopes.

You'll need to use your Bearer token to request the `/oauth/userinfo/` endpoint to find the user's actual base URL. In the Demo environment, that will be `https://demo.docusign.net`, but in Production there are several possibilities.

More information about the User Info endpoint is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Mind blowing that this is not in their docs